# Java : generic classes

Tags: java

I read this code from my book:

```
class B extends A {...}
class G<E> {
public E e;
}
G<B> gb = new G<B>();
G<A> ga = gb;
ga.e = new A();
B b = gb.e; // Error
```

Why `B b = gb.e;` arise an error? We didn't assign anything to b, and for that gb.e is from type B.

Comment: Are you certain that the error occurs only in the line `B b = gb.e;`? And not before, in `G<A> ga = gb;` ?

Comment: @Vineet Reynolds: No. because B<A then G(B)<B(A) is legal

Comment: I'm afraid, that is simply not [the case, at least for me](http://www.ideone.com/6gREv). Feel free to post code reproduces the same error, in the same line. In my opinion, and that of the Eclipse compiler, javac and ideone, the line `G<A> ga = gb;` ought to give an error, because of strict typing checks employed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your exact setup, I've obtained an error from the compiler (Sun Java Compiler version 1.6.x) at the line where you attempt to create the second reference to the instance of the object G:

```
G.java:6: incompatible types
found   : G<B>
required: G<A>
                G<A> ga = gb;
                          ^
1 error
```

Attempting to swap where the conversion happens also fails:

Code:

```
G<A> ga = new G<A>();
G<B> gb = ga;
gb.e = new A();
B b = gb.e;
```

Error:

```
G.java:6: inconvertible types
found   : G<A>
required: G<B>
                G<B> gb = (G<B>)ga;
                                ^
G.java:7: incompatible types
found   : A
required: B
                gb.e = new A();
                       ^
2 errors
```

Are you positive this isn't an issue with the prior lines? I'm not having luck with this case.

Even if the case is that you managed to make it that far, this should still fail because of not knowing the proper type of when trying to get a new B reference. Since you can only convert upward (so, `A instance = new B()` would be OK. `B instance = new A()` would not be) it wouldn't makes sense to take the instance of A and move it down the hierarchy to a type of B.

Answer (score 0):

you are attempting to cast a class to one of its subclasses and not the other way around.

```
A a;
B b;

a = new B(); // works because B is a subclass of A
b = new A(); // fails because A is a superclass of B
```

Comment: but why gb is from type A? is the line: 'ga.e = new A();' define for gb and for ga that they are from type A?